# Check if rows in one dataframe exist in another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a data frame A `dfA` like this:

[image]

And another data frame B `dfB` which looks like this:

[image]

I want to add a column 'Exist' to `dfA` so that if User and Movie both exist in `dfB` then 'Exist' is True, otherwise it is False.
So `dfA` should become like this:

[image]

Comment: Please dont use png for data or tables, use text.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with parameter `indicator`, then remove column `Rating` and use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['User','Movie'], how='left', indicator='Exist')
df.drop('Rating', inplace=True, axis=1)
df['Exist'] = np.where(df.Exist == 'both', True, False)
print (df)
   User  Movie  Exist
0     1    333  False
1     1   1193   True
2     1      3  False
3     2    433  False
4     3     54   True
5     3    343  False
6     3     76   True
```

Comment: It will be useful to indicate that the objective of the OP requires a left outer join. More details here: https://realpython.com/pandas-merge-join-and-concat/#how-to-merge