# Check if a row in a pandas dataframe exists in other dataframes and assign points depending on which dataframes it also belongs to

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38855204/check-if-a-row-in-one-data-frame-exist-in-another-data-frame) question this problem is solved partially to check if a row in a dataframe exists in another one.

What I have is many dataframes df1, df2, df3, df4 etc.
which are subsets of a larger dataframe df.

Now, for each row in df, I want to create a new column "RATING", and I want to assign a value.

For example if row1 in df is contained in df1 add 50 points, if it is also contained in df2 add another 30 points, in df3 add 40 points, in df4 subtract 10 points, etc.

row1 then will have a new column "RATING" with the total.
Then do the same for row2, etc.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Apply the exact methodology of the other question you are pointing at to get one additional boolean column per dataframe. You will end up with n extra columns being Exist_in_df1, Exist_in_df2, ..., Exist_in_dfn

Now you have a simple boolean matrix to work with against which you can apply your simple rating logic