# Pandas Compare two data frames and look for duplicate elements

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, equals

I want to compare df and df_equal.
df contains several individual data frames

```
    import pandas as pd

    df1 = pd.DataFrame([[ 'b', 'b', 'b' ]],
        columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

Output:
    a   b   c
0   b   b   b
```

```
    df2 = pd.DataFrame([[ 'x', 'x', 'x' ]],
        columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
Output:
    a   b   c
0   x   x   x
```

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
    a   b   c
0   b   b   b
0   x   x   x
```

```
df_equal = pd.DataFrame([[ 'x', 'x', 'x' ]],
    columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

how can i check df for duplicate?

I tried .equals:

```
for row in df:
    df.equals(exactly_equal)
```

my desired output:

```
False #first row in df 
True  #second row in df
```

Comment: Are you talking about something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38855204/check-if-a-row-in-one-data-frame-exist-in-another-data-frame?

Comment: @formicaman 
Thank you, had already searched for the same question as mine but found no suitable one. 
This should help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just iterate over the rows, for example to compare every row of `df` to `df2` (given that `df2` only has one row):

```py
for row in range(len(df)):
    print((df.iloc[row, ].values == df2.values).all())
```

```py
False
True
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean by comparing duplicates, it's very vague.
Do you mean comparing duplicates in the rows or the columns or values to values in the data?

But, we can compare the values to each other in both rows by:

```
df.values[0]==df.values[1]
# [False False False]
```

Or we compare row 2 indexed as [1] to the whole dataset by:

```
df.values[:][1]==df.values[:][:]
#[[False False False]
#[ True  True  True]]
```

I think this is what you want. I'm sorry if I don't fully get your answer.
Try and let me know!

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[ 'b', 'b', 'b' ]],
        columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[ 'x', 'x', 'x' ]],
        columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

df = pd.concat([df1, df2])

df_equal = pd.DataFrame([[ 'x', 'x', 'x' ]],
    columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])



for i in range(0,len(df)):
    print((df.iloc[i].equals(df_equal.iloc[0])))
```

will do the job