# Compare elements in 2 columns in a dataframe to 2 input values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to compare values in 2 columns of a dataframe from the input and check for equality:

My input is a list like:

```
ABC BCD
QWE XYZ
MNO PQR
```

My dataframe looks like:

```
St1  St2

ABC  BCD
PQR  XYZ
MNO  PQR
```

I want to check of the input is present in my dataframe. And if yes, then corresponding to each of the values, I append a "Yes" or "No" on the basis of whether it is present or not.

I am trying to do this:

```
for i in range(len(pairs)):
    if df_final['Stock1']==pairs[i][0]:
        df["corr"] = "Yes"
```

This doesnt work and give the following error:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How can it be rectified?

I have tried this as well:

```
k = pairs[0]
df[(df[['St1','St2']].values == k).all(axis=1)]
```

where pairs is the input

Comment: What's in pairs?

Comment: @NYCCoder The input in the question is there in the pairs

Comment: Ok then what is in `df_final`. Can you paste a sample of that?

Comment: @NYCCoder 
The dataframe is the df_final with columns St1 and St2. I want 1 column with a yes or no if they exist

i have also added 1 more approach. Though it doesnt work when run for all tuples in the list of input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a solution for you based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38855394/14314520). However, you need to make the column names consistent in both data sets:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['St1','St2'], how='left', indicator='Exist')
df1['corr'] = np.where(df['Exist'] == 'both', True, False)
df1

   St1  St2   corr
0  ABC  BCD   True
1  QWE  DAS  False
2  MNO  PQR   True
```

**Data**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'St1': ['ABC', 'QWE', 'MNO'], 'St2': ['BCD', 'DAS', 'PQR']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'St1': ['ABC', 'PQR', 'MNO'], 'St2': ['BCD', 'XYZ', 'PQR']})
```